# Шифрование в режиме однократного гаммирования

Tags: шифрование

Нам известны шифротексты(С1 И С2) открытых текстов (P1 И P2),шифротексты получаются путем сложения по модулю 2 открытых текстов и ключа шифрования, можно ли без определения ключа вычислить открытые тексты P1 и P2 или нужно знать хотя бы один из двух открытых тестов ?

Comment: если вы имеете ввиду, что гаммы для обоих сообщений создавались из одного ключа и следовательно одинаковы, то выполнив C1 xor C2 мы получим P1 xor P2. Далее все зависит от природы самих открытых текстов, сможем ли делать какие то предположения по ним. Если это именно тексты (на каком нибудь конкретном языке) с пробелами, то мы как минимум получим информацию о том, где буквы у них совпадали и сможем догадаться где могли быть пробелы (правда не поймем в каком из сообщений), зная пробелы можем получить предположения по гамме в этих байтах и следовательно по возможным буквам в тех позициях

Comment: Mike а есть ли универсальный алгоритм для этого случая или самому нужно анализировать?

Comment: Не знаю, у профессиональных крипоаналитиков наверняка есть. Есть наверняка и куча готовых методик и программ. Но я ничего специализированного никогда не изучал. Использую то, что сам придумываю. Вот вчера еще подумал, что имея p1 ^ p2 и предполагая на каком языке написан текст можно взять словник этого языка, выполнить xor всех слов со всеми остальными (там конечно очень много комбинаций, но компы сейчас потянут) и поискать полученные комбинации в p1^p2 по крайней мере есть верятность что в начале строки получится, дальше надо смотреть

Comment: ну или xor известных слов с началом строки и проверять не появилось ли что то похожее на существующее слово